# Python requests.get showing 404 while url does exists

Tags: python, session, python-2.7, python-requests

http://www.leboncoin.fr/montres_bijoux/671762293.htm

I'm trying to open this url

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/34.0.1847.116 Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36'
s.headers['Host'] = 'www.leboncoin.fr'
url = 'http://www.leboncoin.fr/montres_bijoux/671762293.htm'
r = s.get(url)
print r.text
```

when I run this script it shows this error, in my terminal,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /montres_bijoux/671762293.htm  was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

while I can open same url in my browser and can see content.

What could be the issue??

Comment: Can you show where you set the value of `url`? You want to make sure it is the full URL (e.g. http://domain.com/asdasd), not just the path part.

Comment: @okoboko : actually this piece of code is in function which take one parameter which is url.

Comment: actually I did same thing in ipython shell and it worked for me too but not when I'm executing same code in file its showing above error?

Comment: what do you mean by "executing  same code in file"? How and where are you running it?

Comment: I created a new file `test.py` and put same code in that and then executing that file as `python test.py`

Comment: works fine running it like that  for me

Comment: Works for me too. And there's no good reason it wouldn't work exactly the same in the interactive interpreter vs. a script, unless (a) you didn't actually copy and paste, but retyped and made a typo, (b) this isn't your actual test case, and you have some non-ASCII characters in your script, and your editor treated them differently from your terminal, or (c) you have multiple Python installations (especially with different versions of `requests` installed), and you're using different ones for the two tests. Are any of those possible?

Comment: Also, why is this tagged python-2.7 and python-3.x? The example code clearly won't work at all in 3.x (the `print` command). And do you have any reason to believe that the actual problem is likely to be related to the Python version?

Comment: are you sure your url is exactly the same in your `test.py` file?

Comment: yeah! as you can see in error `/montres_bijoux/671762293.htm` 
Let me figure it out by putting checks, will back soon.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Okk! the problem is I'm reading this url from a text file. when I put this url manually in function call it works fine but if I read that file and directly call function with that url, give me error.
I have put 3-4 checks while reading file, url is perfectly coming form the file even I tried to print that url inside the called function and I'm receiving that url in function too. still have no clue what is happening ?

Comment: Could you add the text file and the code where you read it to the post so we can help you?

Comment: @user3810188: Try `print repr(url)` instead of `print url`. I'll bet there's actually a `'\n'` at the end of it. Or, if not that, some other not-easily-visible character.

Comment: when you print `repr(url)` what do you see? If you use `url.rstrip()` it  will probably work.

Comment: Okk Guyzz thank you very much. `repr` helped me.
there was actually a space after `.htm`. 
Its working great now.

One more thing, as I'm new on SOF. What should I do with this question as it doesn't have any answer. should I delete or you guyz can add answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without even waiting for your test, I'm pretty confident I know what your bug is.

> I put this url manually in function call it works fine but if I read that file and directly call function with that url, give me error. I have put 3-4 checks while reading file, url is perfectly coming form the file even I tried to print that url inside the called function and I'm receiving that url in function too. still have no clue what is happening ?

Most likely you're reading the URL with something like `for line in file:` or `file.readline` or some other function that preserves newlines. So, what you actually end up with is not this:

```
url = 'http://www.leboncoin.fr/montres_bijoux/671762293.htm'
```

… but this:

```
url = 'http://www.leboncoin.fr/montres_bijoux/671762293.htm\n'
```

The latter will be escaped by `requests` into something that's a perfectly good URL for a resource that doesn't exist, hence the 404 error.

The best way to check this is to `print repr(url)` instead of `print(url)`. This will also find other possible problems, like embedded nonprintable characters. It won't find *everything*, like Unicode characters that look like `.` but actually aren't, but it's a good first test. (And if that doesn't find it, for a second test, copy and paste from the output, quotes and all, into your test script.)

If this is the problem, the fix is simple:

```
url = url.rstrip()
```